# prepared mysql statements and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

**Solved the problem earlier today. In the 2nd line of code `global $db,$tags`; was overwriting `if($this->has_lead_type_selected($person['ID'],$tags))` which caused the global $tags to overwrite $tags at the lower portion of code. So the global var was empty because it was before the actual $tags var was given a function.**

When an HTML form is submitted to our REST API it sends data called 'lead_type' which are simply tags to identify the lead being sent.

User select these tags from a tag cloud. If a form is submitted to the API with one of these tags (lead_type) and any of our users profiles match those tags (they selected in their tag cloud). The user is sent a SMS to notify them.

Everything posts to the database tables, the API works but everyone of the users still gets a SMS even if they don't have matching tags. If I comment out the line (i'll show the rest of the code below) an SMS is sent to everyone. If I leave it uncommented no SMS is sent to anyone.

```
if($this->has_lead_type_selected($person['ID'],$tags))
```

Here is how the code flows.

```
    }
private function has_lead_type_selected($user_id,$tags){
    global $db,$tags;
    $lead_types = explode(',',$tags);
    $user_lead_types = $db
                    ->where('user_id',$user_id)
                    ->where('lead_type_id', $lead_types, 'IN')
                    ->get('user_lead_types');   

    return sizeof($user_lead_types) > 0;

}


//Get lead types from API post and create $tags 
            $lead_types = $this->request['leadData']['lead_types'];
            $strTags = array();
            if(!empty($lead_types))
                $strTags = explode(',',$lead_types);

            $tags = '';

            $lead_types_objects = $db->where('lead_type', $strTags,'IN')->get('lead_types');

            foreach($lead_types_objects as $l)
            {
                if($tags=='')
                    $tags = $l['id'];
                else
                    $tags.=',' .$l['id'];
            }
```

We then send them a SMS if the form tags matched the users cloud tags.

```
global $sid,$token;
            $client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);

        $content_data = [         
            "leadname" => $posted_name,
            "leadzipcode" => $posted_zipcode,
            "leadphone" => $posted_phone,
            "leademail" => $posted_email,
            "leadtags" => $lead_types           
            ];

        //Replace Content
        foreach($content_data as $index => $value){
            $lead_sms_template = str_replace("|".$index."|", $value, $lead_sms_template);
        }

        // Step 5: Loop over all our friends. $number is a phone number above, and 
        // $name is the name next to it
        foreach ($people as $person) {
            try{
                //commented temporarily -- uncommented below to try to solve issue of texting everyone still
                if($this->has_lead_type_selected($person['ID'],$tags))
                {
                    $number = $person['phone_no'];
                    $name = $person['first_name']. ' '. $person['last_name'];
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: has_lead_type_selected should check if user has one selected or all of selected tags ?

Comment: Solved the problem earlier today. In the 2nd line of code global $db,$tags; was overwriting if($this->has_lead_type_selected($person['ID'],$tags)) which caused the global $tags to overwrite $tags at the lower portion of code. So the global var was empty because it was before the actual $tags var was given a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 2nd line of code global `$db`,`$tags`; was overwriting `if($this->has_lead_type_selected($person['ID'],$tags))` which caused the global `$tags` to overwrite `$tags` at the lower portion of code. So the global var was empty because it was before the actual `$tags` var was given a function.

Comment: thank you for fixing my comment, how do I make an answer to my own question in the future?

Comment: Hey Cody, you can simply put in the answer field as you would on any other question.